# Vuforia Marker ID changes from one scene to another in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I am using Vuforia 8.1.12 and Unity 2019.4. My issue is the following:

1. In scene 1 in Unity, I have a UI without ARCamera.
2. In scene 2 in Unity, I have 3 Image Target markers and ARCamera.

Then, when I move from scene 1 to scene 2, the vuforia marker IDs are: 0,1,2. Then, I go back to scene 1 using (SceneManager.LoadScene(0)). Then, I need to go to Scene 2 again but now the markers are assigned the following IDs: 3,4,5 respectively. Since the marker IDs are changing, I cannot detect the marker using the corresponding ID because they dynamically change.

Is there any way of managing this? How to avoid Vuforia assigning additional IDs to the markers each time the scene load?

Thank you!

I tried to use a Singleton design pattern using the DontDestroyOnLoad to keep the Image Target instances between the scene but Vuforia is still assigning new IDs for the markers each time the scene loads. I also tried to disable the VuforiaBehavior script but then video background do not starts.

Comment: What feature are you using? Vumakrs? Image targets?

Comment: Thank you @emay! I am using Image Targets.

Comment: are the markers identical in appearance or are they different? If they are different do they have different names? If yes then you can use the name (and not the ID) to distinguish who is who across sessions.

Comment: Thank you @emay!! Using the marker name instead of the marker ID solved the issue. Thank you so much!